# A way to turn one List into another (via polymorphism, child and parent classes)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, inheritance, collections, polymorphism

Alright, so I have the following method:

```
private List<Store> NextPrevious(List<Store> model, int numFields, int page, ref bool nextRef, ref bool previousRef)
{
    if (model.Count > numFields && page == 0)
    {
        model = model.Skip(page * (numFields - 1)).Take(numFields - 1).ToList();
        next = true;
        previous = false;
    }
    else if (page > 0 && model.Skip(page + (numFields - 2)).Count() <= (numFields - 1))
    {
        model = model.Skip(page + (numFields - 2)).Take(numFields - 1).ToList();
        next = false;
        previous = true;
    }
    else if (page > 0 && model.Count > (page + 1))
    {
        model = model.Skip(page + (numFields - 2)).Take(numFields - 2).ToList();
        next = true;
        previous = true;
    }
    return model.ToList();
}
```

I'd call the method like this:

```
model.Groups = NextPrevious(model.Groups.ToList<Store>(), 3, groupPage, ref next, ref previous);
```

`model.Groups` is of type `List<Group>`. `Group` is a child class of a class `Store`. Now, is there a way to reference the group when I'm sending it in the method (`ref`), or at least return it, like I tried, unsuccessfully, and make it work. Right now if I type this and try to run it, I get an error:

```
Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<(path)Store> to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<(path)Group>'
```

I know what the error means, but I just don't have the knowledge to go around it, so I'm asking here for help. By the way, I can't cast it as `return model.ToList<Group>()` neither, since the method is created so it could be used for other class objects that inherit the `Store` class.

Thanks!

Comment: The last `.ToList()` is unnecessary. And why not use `out` instead of `ref` as usual. Both changes I suggest requires there to be a "catch-all" `else` in the end, to follow all those `else if`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solution could be changing the `NextPrevious` as a [generic method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/twcad0zb.aspx) and declaring the following [constraint](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970.aspx) on the type parameter:

```
private List<T> NextPrevious<T>(List<T> model, int numFields, int page, ref bool nextRef, ref bool previousRef) where T:Store
{
  //...
}
```

This way you just need  to do this:

```
model.Groups = NextPrevious(model.Groups, 3, groupPage, ref next, ref previous);//call model.Groups.ToList() in case the Groups property is not a List<Group>
```

You can omit the type argument at the time you call the `NextPrevious<T>` method because the compiler will infer it  based on the first method argument you pass.

Comment: Nice, this one works out even better! (performance wise), I'm pretty fresh, coming from Java, but I did know templates back in C++, yet they didn't really cross my mind. Thank you, this solution is pretty much what I was looking for! :)

Comment: @NemanjaT They are not called "templates" in C#, they are call generics. In this case the _method_ is generic (takes a type argument `T` (in angular brackets `<...>`) alongside with the ordinary arguments). It can also be a class (or interface, or struct, or delegate type) which is generic, such as the type `class List<T> { ... }`.

Answer (score 1):

Well, one way you could do this is use `Cast()`, something like:

```
model.Groups = NextPrevious(...).Cast<Group>().ToList();
```

This *will* blow up at runtime with an `InvalidCastException` if any of the objects returned from `NextPrevious` can't be casted to a `Group`, but...

You could also within `NextPrevious()` cast before you return,

```
....
return model.Cast<Group>.ToList();
```

Comment: Casting seams to be working, thank you! Let me just run a few more tests and I'll let you know in a minute! :) If it's alright, you'll get the confirmed tag.

Comment: I'd wait on that - I mean if it works for you great - but someone is very likely to come along with a different, and perhaps better solution.

Comment: It seams to be working, so I'll leave it as is. If I don't find a better solution by morning, I'll tag you up. Thank you again! :)